# I am getting value with this pointer object but dont know how to store if more values are there

Tags: javascript

when checking multiple  check boxes, then how to store below values?

```
<input type="checkbox" id='+k+' amount ='+cost+' onclick=\"checkout(this)\">
```

In function..

var total = obj.getAttribute("amount");

can I store this total in array for more check boxes are checked

Comment: Could you describe your question a bit more??

Comment: i have to add values related to check box , i am getting value when single check box checked, but number of check boxes are checked then i have to add those values....how can i store values  when checkbox checked

Comment: You want to sum everytime user check or uncheck checkbox or you want to send sum on form submit

Comment: yes, i want to add when check box checked itself..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use global variable like below

```
 <body >

     <input type="checkbox"  value ="1" onclick="javascript:sum(this);" />
    <input type="checkbox"  value ="2" onclick="javascript:sum(this);" />
     <input type="checkbox"  value ="3" onclick="javascript:sum(this);" />

 </body>


 <script>
  var globalSum = 0;
  function sum(obj){

  if(obj.checked){
  globalSum = globalSum  + parseInt(obj.value);
  }else{
  globalSum = globalSum  - parseInt(obj.value);
  }


  alert(globalSum );
  }
```

Comment: thanks for reply...its good..but every time its taking single value..its not  do total